# Time complexity: if/else under for loop

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

If in a situation like the following (an if/else statement under a for loop) would the time complexity be O(n) or O(n^2):

```
def power_dic (n,k)
    if (k=0):
        return 1
    elif (k mod 2 = 0):
        return power(n*n, k/2)
    else
        return n*power_dic(n, k-1)
```

The above code computes n^k.

Comment: To the close voter: How is it that "This question currently includes multiple questions in one?" The question seems perfectly focused to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situations like this, you need to analyze how the code behaves as a whole. How many times each of the return statements are going to be called, the relations between then and the input.

---

**In this specific example:**

The time complexity is `O(logk)` (assuming all int multiplications are `O(1)`).

For each time `return power(n*n, k/2)` is called, `return n*power_dic(n, k-1)` is called at most once<sup>(1)</sup>.

In addition, `return power(n*n, k/2)` is called `O(logk)` times, since you reduce it by half each time it is called.

This means, your total complexity is `2*logn`, which is `O(logk)`.

---

(1) Except maybe the last bit, where you call `power_dic(n,1)`, but that one time does not change the answer.

Comment: I would call it `O(length of k)`, or linear time in the size of the input.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Thanks for feedback, changed it to `O(logk)`, which is I think more clear, wdyt?